# Setting the rowsource property of a combobox in another database?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I've looked all over the place for this and I can't find it; I looked in ADO, and DAO.

Is there a way using VBA to edit the row source property of a combo box on a form in another `.mdb` file?  I have to make this change on a bunch of `.mdb` files and I'd rather use a script to do it, than to do it one at a time.

Comment: Try to copy form from another db to current, update rowsource in design mode and copy the object back

Comment: Are the form and combo box names the same in all those databases, or must you inspect each form and find a combo whose Record Source matches your target string?

Comment: @HansUp They're all the same.

Comment: @HansUp I just don't want to repeat all of that manually...many, many, many times...when I can write a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COM automation to create an Access application session where you open a database, open the target form in design mode, and then alter the target combo box's *Row Source*.

```vb
Public Sub AlterComboRowSource(ByVal pDb As String, _
        ByVal pForm As String, _
        ByVal pCombo As String, _
        ByVal pRowSource As String, _
        Optional ByVal pEdit As Boolean = False)

    Dim objAccess As Access.Application
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim cbo As ComboBox

    Set objAccess = New Access.Application
    objAccess.Visible = True '<- useful while debugging
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase pDb, True
    objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm pForm, acDesign
    Set frm = objAccess.Forms(pForm)
    Set cbo = frm.Controls(pCombo)
    Debug.Print cbo.RowSource

    If pEdit = True Then
        cbo.RowSource = pRowSource
        objAccess.DoCmd.Close acForm, pForm, acSaveYes
    End If
    objAccess.Quit acQuitSaveNone
End Sub
```

Here is my test procedure, which demonstrates how to use the first procedure:

```vb
Public Sub test_AlterComboRowSource()
    Const cstrCombo As String = "cmbEmployeeName"
    Const cstrForm As String = "frmLogin"
    Dim strDbPath As String
    Dim strSelect As String

    strDbPath = "C:\Users\hans\Documents\Access\Scratch.accdb"
    strSelect = "SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName & ' ' & e.LastName AS [Employee Name] " & _
        "FROM tblEmployees AS e " & _
        "WHERE e.Inactive=False ORDER BY 2;"

    AlterComboRowSource strDbPath, cstrForm, cstrCombo, strSelect, True
End Sub
```

Those procedures worked as intended when I tested them in Access 2010.

It should be more efficient to do `Set objAccess = New Access.Application` just once, and then re-use `objAccess`, opening each of your databases, altering the combo *Row Source*, and then closing the database.

However since this may be a one-off situation, perhaps you don't care much about execution speed.

Comment: Will this work if I'm using a QueryDef for the row source, by just setting the combobox rowsource to it's name?

Comment: Yes, `RowSource` is a string value which can be a `SELECT` statement or the name of a table or saved query.  But does the database already contain your named query or must you create that query first?